# Being+past participle as a gerund

Tags: passive-voice, gerunds, prepositional-phrases, present-participles

I've read that "being+past participle" is used in participle. But I'm confused to have found the following sentences written in one of my grammar book (This book isn't available in internet) as gerunds. These sentences are:

> 1. He is afraid of being hated.
> 2. I remember being taken to Delhi as a small boy.
> 3. Being frightened wouldn't solve any problems.

My questions:

1. What's the meanings of above sentences?
2. In which condition this "being+past participle" construction is used as gerunds to make sentences?

Comment: @someone, I don't know what downvote mean, why there's downvote here in the question?

Comment: Not my down-vote. I have no idea why it got a down-vote. I liked this question. A good learner's question. +1 for you :-)

Answer (score 3):

### SENTENCE 1:

> He is afraid of being hated.

You have to learn how the adjective - *afraid* - is used in a sentence. What it licenses etc. A good place to look for those things is a good learners' dictionary. Look [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/afraid).

You see there?

- **afraid of doing something** - *I started to feel afraid of going out alone at night.*

So the adjective - *afraid* - licenses a Preposition Phrase (PP) - *of doing something* - headed by the head preposition - *of*. Inside the PP, the head preposition - *of* - take a Gerund-Participle form of verb - *doing something* - as a complement.

Now that you know about the usage of the adjective - *afraid*, consider the following sentence -

> He is afraid of feeding his dogs.

*He is afraid* is fine. Now, what he fears? This is to be introduced by a PP headed by a preposition - *of*. Here *he is to feed the dogs* and he fears to perform that action. So *feeding the dogs* is what he fears. This Gerund-Participle form of verb - *feeding the dogs* - will be the complement of the preposition - *of* - inside the PP.

Now concentrate on your sentence -

*He is afraid* is fine. What he fears? *that people will hate him*. We can't use *hating him* as a complement of *of* inside the PP. Why? Because then it would mean that the action - *hating* - to be performed by the subject of the sentence - *he*. But that is not the intended meaning. So we have to look for other alternatives. What he fears? *(he is) to be hated (by people)* is what he fears. That gives the intended meaning. So *of being hated* can act as a complement of the adjective - *afraid*.

> He is **afraid** *of being hated*.

### SENTENCE 2:

> I remember being taken to Delhi as a small boy.

I guess you don't have any problem with the part *as a small boy*, so for simplicity I remove that part.

> I remember being taken to Delhi.

So what I said earlier? Learn the usage of words. Here the verb - *remember*. [This](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/remember?q=remember) will help.

- **remember doing something** *Do you remember switching the lights off before we came out?*

What you remember? *switching the lights off* Who is performing the action of *switching the lights off*? The subject - *you* - itself.

But in your sentence it's a bit different. The action of *taking to Delhi* is not being performed by the subject - *I*. But by some other person.

What do *I* remember? *(I am) being taken to Delhi (by some one)* is what I remember. So it's

> I **remember** *being taken to Delhi*.

Hope I could help. You can ask in comments if you need any more clarification.

Comment: from India,I think you well addressed my question. Thank you.But I still have some questions for clarifcation.

Comment: @yubrajsharma You welcome :-) The other answer is also good. Tell me your doubts.

Comment: from india,Do you mean that 'afraid of' and 'remember' only follow 'ing form' in active voice sentences.so,It's the passive form "being+p.p" in my question?

Comment: @yubrajsharma In both cases it's *ing form of verb*. But one is in active voice, and one is in passive voice. In you question the part that acts as a complement of *afraid* or *remember* is in passive voice. The action is not performed by the subject of the sentence, but by some other person.

Comment: from india, I don't know what you mean by "one is active and one is in passive". BUT i see both the sentences in my questions are in passive. "Being hated and Being taken"

Comment: from india could you please respond to my comment

Comment: @yubrajsharma sorry for late reply. Yes in your question both are passive.

Comment: from India,At last,what do you think of these sentences:1.I don't like being asked many questions. 2.Being frightened wouldn't solve any problem.  Please clarify these sentences.

Comment: @yubrajsharma hmmm sentence #1 *being asked* is passive. Sentence #2, *being frightened* is ambiguous. It could either be passive form, or *frightened* could be an adjective.

Comment: @india,Do you consider the second question to be a gerund following ing form? This is the sentence that I took from@cardinals answer.How would it look like in active voice sentence.could you change it in active voice sentence? or it's participle.I'm totally confused now.

Comment: @yubrajsharma all the sentences being discussed here are in active voice, but in the Gerund-participle clause it's passive voice. The sentence with *frightened* is different. *frightened* here is adjective. Will talk about it later, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: could you please include about this in your answer itself by editing.I would be greatfull to you.

Comment: Thank you. And I hope you would like to try to solve this question too http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105234/havingp-p-as-a-gerund/105286#105286

Answer (score 1):

I start by expressing the meaning of those sentences:

> He is afraid of being hated.

This sentence means that he's afraid that other people hate him. In this sentence "of being hated" is the complement of the adjective afraid. In fact, the adjective afraid ***licenses*** prepositional phrases beginning with **of**.

> I remember being taken to Delhi as a small boy.

This sentence means You remember that someone took you to Delhi when you was a small boy. Here **being taken** is the passive form of the "taking". Why passive? Because you want to say that you were taken by someone else. I should also mention that after some verbs (including remember) we can use **verb+ing**; for example consider these sentences in active voice:

- I vaguely remember locking the car.
- I started working on the problem.
- I finished writing the letter.

---

Being as a gerund usually takes adjectives, nouns or prepositions as matter of the fact that such phrases refer to conditions and states:

- Being a teacher is difficult.
- Being frightened would not solve any problems.
- Being on the plane can be dangerous.

However, note that being + noun/adjective/prepositions can also be used as adverbial participles:

- Being a teacher, I want to answer this question
- Being afraid of height, I didn't go with my friends to the journey.
- Being on the plane, I couldn't use my cell-phone.

Comment: ,could you please deal with my second question ?I want to learn about the situation or condition in which the constitution is to be used. or the use of this construction as gerunds.

Comment: @yubrajsharma I think I've already addressed that issue.

Comment: I haven't got you yet

Comment: @yubrajsharma So, please pinpoint the bottleneck. What is your exact problem? I have added some points, though.

Comment: I See both answer usfull, what I'm confused is about "being+p.p" construction  and how to use it in sentences, so Now i'm discussing with @man from india about it.

Comment: @yubrajsharma "being + PP" can be used in several ways, you should be specific. For instance, I mentioned adverbial participles.

Comment: ,What kind of sentence that you mentioned "Being frightened wouldn't solve any problem"