# Having+past participle as a gerund

Tags: gerunds, past-participles

I've read that 'having+past participle' is used in the perfect participle. Now I'm confused to have found the following sentences written in a grammar book(which isn't available in internet) and in this website http://www.myenglishteacher.net/gerunds.html as gerunds. Which calls it as perfect  gerund.
The sentences are:

1. I heard of his having won a prize.
2. The mirror showed no prints of having been touched.
3. She was accused of having stolen my bag.

My questions:

1. How are these sentences with 'having+p.p' uses of the gerund?
2. Could you please tell me how to use 'having+p.p' as gerunds in sentences with examples?

Answer (score 1):

> I have won a prize.

This is *win* in the present perfect sense.

- Present perfect sense: It means you won a prize in the past, then X, then now.  X is not specified here and is not required to be specified.

  - Reasons for X not being specified include emphasis that something's in the past, communicating that something happened outside of the recent past, communicating that a state change is completed and not in progress, and expecting X to be filled in from context.
  - A possible fill-in for X is "the contest ended" or "I actually received the prize."

> I heard about him having won a prize.

This is kinda-sorta *win* in the present perfect sense in gerund forum.  It means he has won a prize, but it's converted to a gerund form so it can be an object of a preposition.

I'm sure I made someone with higher rep than me angry at saying that gerunds can have perfect forms.  I don't *really* think gerunds can actually have perfect tenses - because A) they aren't even pure verbs and B) it doesn't work at all with past perfect.

What I think is really going on is something like this:

> I am having lunch now.
>
> I am having my nails done.
>
> I am having my car repaired.

A meaning of *have* is "to take in" or "to receive or undergo an action."

> I am having my clothes tailored = I'm receiving the action of "clothes tailored" from someone.

So:

> I heard about him having won a prize = I heard about him *having undergone* the action of "win a prize."
>
> I haven't been there in two years ... I wanted to know about him not having been there in two years = I wanted to know about him not having undergone the action of "being there".

Comment: I haven't got you yet, I don't know why you are using 'x' mark in your answer, I don't find it helpfull at all.

Comment: could you please make it understandable for me?